# Excel automation: How do I set the range?

Tags: c#, excel

The standard method to get the range of an Excel spreadsheet in use is the UsedRange-method. I can copy all the used cells like this:

```
xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Copy(misValue);
```

Unfortunately it is not a good method because cells are "activated" if the user write something in one and then delete it again. It can have the unintentional consequense that thousands of empty rows and columns are marked (and printed out in my case).

So I have translated [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=82) method to C# to get a more accurate range. On debugging, it gives FirstRow = 1, FirstColumn = 1, LastRow = 600, LastColumn = 2, which is what I wanted using my test worksheet as input.

But I still need to set the real used range and copy it. In VB, it is done like this:

```
Set RealUsedRange = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```

How do I set a range and copy it in C#? I want to replace this line:

```
xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Copy(misValue);
```

With the (1,1) to (600,2) range.

I have tried this:

```
return Excel.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[FirstRow, FirstColumn], xlWorkSheet.Cells[LastRow, LastColumn]);
```

But it gives Excel.Range is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context. I don't know the proper way to write it.

```
    // this struct is just to make the result more readable
    public struct RealRange
    {
        public int FirstRow;
        public int FirstColumn;
        public int LastRow;
        public int LastColumn;

        public RealRange(int fr, int fc, int lr, int lc)
        {
            FirstRow = fr;
            FirstColumn = fc;
            LastRow = lr;
            LastColumn = lc;
        }
    }

    public RealRange RealUsedRange()
    {
        int FirstRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
            "*",
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("IV65536", misValue),
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
            Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            ).Row;

        int FirstColumn = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
            "*",
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("IV65536", misValue),
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,
            Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            ).Column;

        int LastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
            "*",
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("IV65536", misValue),
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
            Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            ).Row;

        int LastColumn = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
            "*",
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("IV65536", misValue),
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,
            Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value
            ).Column;

       return new RealRange(FirstRow, FirstColumn, LastRow, LastColumn);
    }
```

**Solution**
Notice I have changed the return value from void to the struct RealRange. This is to make the result more readable. The 'range' in a spreadsheet is the span between 2 cells. You can copy the range by using the get_range-function like I did below. Thank you to D. Hilgarth for the help.

```
rr = RealUsedRange();
this.workSheet.get_Range(
   this.workSheet.Cells[rr.FirstRow, rr.FirstColumn], 
   this.workSheet.Cells[rr.LastRow, rr.LastColumn]).Copy(missing);
```

Comment: Don't edit the answer, edit your own question with the solution and it's up to Daniel to edit his own answer..

Comment: He almost had the solution. I added it to my original answer insted.

Comment: cheers, that's the way you should do it. You can comment on his answer so he can see your solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `RealUsedRange` to return an object of type `Range`, just as the original function does.

Something like this:

```
public Range RealUsedRange()
{
    // ...
    return xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[FirstRow, FirstColumn],
                                 xlWorkSheet.Cells[LastRow, LastColumn]);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this: return Excel.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[FirstRow, FirstColumn], xlWorkSheet.Cells[LastRow, LastColumn]);. But it gives "Excel.Range is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context". This is my problem:-(

Comment: try a `new` after `return` as shown in my answer. BTW: What syntax error? You really should provide all the information you have the first time... It's annoying to have to ask for every bit of info...

Comment: A new syntax error: "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'"

Comment: The first syntax error was the one in my first comment:  "Excel.Range is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context". Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Your latest gives a new syntax error: "'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet' does not contain a definition for 'Range' and no extension method 'Range' accetping a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet' could be found."

Comment: That's strange, because it should have it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192736.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Please try using IntelliSense to find the right property or method. Maybe there is a get_Range method instead.

Comment: xl.WorkSheet.get_Range(object Cell1, object Cell2) exists!

Comment: xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[600, 2]).Copy(misValue); This works! I still think the documentation is very hard to work with. But thank you very much. I had looked at get_range before, but hadn't figured it out until now.